# grab other cell values based on previous cell value in a row from excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, openxml

i am trying to read the data from excel sheet using open xml sdk,I have column structure in excel sheet like as in below image

[image]

I need to get the values for the cell `station` and `WMO#` when the `Country` is `USA` and i do have data for country `USA` in the excel sheet but could not be able to figure it out how to get the data.

I am using below code to get the data

```
        string filePath = @"C:\data.xlsx";
        using FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        using SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false);
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

        Sheet firstSheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First();
        Worksheet sheet = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(firstSheet.Id)).Worksheet;

        var cells = sheet.Descendants<Cell>();
        var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();

        foreach (Row row in rows.Skip(5))
        {
            int cellCount = 0;
            foreach (Cell c in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                string stringValue = "";
                if ((c.DataType != null) && (c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
                {
                    int ssid = int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text);
                    stringValue = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;
                }
                else if (c.CellValue != null)
                {
                    stringValue = c.CellValue.Text;
                }
                cellCount++;
                Console.WriteLine("Cell Number:"+ cellCount + "CellValue:" + stringValue);
            }
        }
```

if country is `USA` only i need to grab the remaining cell data in a row,I am using open XML library for this.

could any one please let me know how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could any one please let me know is there any other approach or any suggestion with current approach

Comment: I'm just learning C# myself, but it looks to me like you are close if that basic loop is working. You just need to add logic check for usa as cellvalue then store the remaining cells in a structure of some sort.